# how can i display last list with no internet (firebase android)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

how can i display last list of users with no internet .

when i use internet the data displays successfully

when iam not using internet there is no data

i need the last data to display in the list with no internet

**Activity**

```
Toolbar tb;
DatabaseReference onlineref;
RecyclerView recyclerview;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<User>list;
AntherUS antherUS;
UserCOntroller adapter;
User p;
TextView title_Txt; 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_);

    antherUS=new AntherUS(list_Activity.this);
    title_Txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_text);


  //  DatabaseReference reference =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    //reference.addValueEventListener(new V)

    //toolbar
    tb=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    title_Txt.setText("  "+antherUS.reading_code()+" ~List");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(antherUS.reading_code());
    int redColorValue = Color.WHITE;


    String smartcode=antherUS.reading_code();

    onlineref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(smartcode+" ~List");
    recyclerview =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recy);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    onlineref.keepSynced(true);

    list=new ArrayList<User>();
    adapter=new UserCOntroller(list_Activity.this,list);


        onlineref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    if (!dataSnapshot1.getKey().equals(antherUS.reading_code()+"pw_Group")) {
                         p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                        String[] Email_part = antherUS.reading_email().split("@");
                        String part1 = Email_part[0];
                        String aa = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                        FirebaseUser userse = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        String as = antherUS.reading_name();
                        if (!aa.equals("chat") && (aa != null) && (!aa.equals(antherUS.reading_holename())) && (!aa.equals(antherUS.reading_name())) && (!aa.equals(userse.getUid()))
                                && (!aa.equals(part1))) {

                            list.add(p);
                            antherUS.writing_numberlist(list.size());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }}
                }

                recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    recyclerview.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0,list.size());
    recyclerview.setItemViewCacheSize(list.size());

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    User user=new User();
    user.setPw_group(antherUS.reading_pwgroup());
    user.setCode(antherUS.reading_code());
    user.setEmail(antherUS.reading_email());
    user.setName(antherUS.reading_name());
    user.setHole(antherUS.reading_holename());

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}

}
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public class UserCOntroller extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserCOntroller.myViewHolder>{

Context context;
ArrayList<User>profiles;
String massemail;

public  UserCOntroller(Context c,ArrayList<User>p){
    context=c;
    profiles=p;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    return new myViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.user_layout,viewGroup,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
    AntherUS antherUS=new AntherUS(context);

    // set names in list
    myViewHolder.user.setText(profiles.get(position).getName());
    final User user=profiles.get(position);


    /// get url
    massemail=user.getEmail();
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(user.getImageUrl())
            .into(myViewHolder.imageView);

myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(context,CHatActivity.class);
       // User user=profiles.get(position);
        //send name and the main name
        intent.putExtra("userid",user.getName());
        intent.putExtra("holeid",user.getHole());
        FirebaseUser user1s=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
});

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return profiles.size();
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView user;
    CircleImageView imageView;
    CardView card;
    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        user=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        imageView=(CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        card=(CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
        card.getBackground().setAlpha(0);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the list data in the local database and when the internet isn't available you should fetch the data from the local db and display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides the option to cache the data locally so that we can use them when we are offline. For more information check the doc [Enabling Offline Capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

To store the data locally you must set setPersistenceEnabled to true

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```